# JMeter - logging with PopUp

Tags: javascript, authentication, controller, popup, jmeter

I need to do logging in JMeter. In Firefox, i go to the website, enter username and passwort and press the login button. Then i check in console which POSTs are shown. I take login data from xml and give it to HTTPRequest as a parameteres in JMeter. And right now i have a problem. This website, before going to the first page after logging, shows JS PopUp with warning (yes or no to choose). JS code to this popup is shown in console as a Response in this POST method. This popup blocked going further - a content from the URL from this POST is "Acces Denied".

How to fix it? I was thinking about some If Controller but I don't have any specific idea.

I would be greatful ;-)

Comment: response to popup either sends some data to the server, or sets some cookie. This is what your script should replicate.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about JavaScript. [JMeter is not a browser](http://jmeter.apache.org/).

> As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.

So JMeter won't be able to "see" the popup or to "type" anything in it. However JMeter can mimic the relevant request just like it is originated from the browser. So instead of building your request manually I would suggest to **[record](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)** it. Even record 2 times so if there are any differences caused by dynamic parameters you could identify and work them around.

Also as JMeter is not a browser it requires some extra configuration in order to be more browser-like, i.e.:

- [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) - to represent browser cookies and deal with cookie-based authentication
- [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request_Defaults) - to represent browser headers e.g. User-Agent
- [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) - to mimic browser cache so in case of subsequent requests to the same URL JMeter wouldn't re-download all associated images

See [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article for detailed explanation of the aforementioned configuration suggestions and few more tips.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ! I recorded it and it helps me a lot. But now a have further issue:
This popup is optional and it is shown when more than 1 user is logged in with the same username. If this happens - I get as a POST response a js code like "new Popup(....etc... ". But when the PopUp won't appear - i get a piece of URL(POST response) which is sticked to a normal URL when there is only 1 user logged. Now I want to consider this two cases. How to do it in JMeter? I made a Response Assertion and as a Pattern to Test I put this piece of URL. If this second condition appers - everything is fine but when this PopUp apers - I would like to stick this piece of URL to the main address and go further.
I have tried to record it but it is just a JavaScript operation and I can't find this moment in JMeter recording. As You said - i have to forget about JavaScript ;)
So, is there any possibility to do it?